# how to prevent dropdownlists with same set of values select same value?

Tags: asp.net, dropdownlistfor

I have 3 dropdowns and  each one is populated with same set of values say a,b and c

eg: if i select 'a' from the dropdown and there is another dropdown with the same value 'a' selected. i should get an err msg.

How is this possible.

Comment: jquery solution /javascript ? c# ?

Comment: c#.. asp.net dropdown list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use CompareValidator control like this:

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <asp:DropDownList ID="ddl1" runat="server">
            <asp:ListItem Text="a" Value="a"></asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Text="b" Value="b"></asp:ListItem>
        </asp:DropDownList>
        <asp:DropDownList ID="ddl2" runat="server">
            <asp:ListItem Text="a" Value="a"></asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Text="b" Value="b"></asp:ListItem>
        </asp:DropDownList>
        <asp:DropDownList ID="ddl3" runat="server">
            <asp:ListItem Text="a" Value="a"></asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Text="b" Value="b"></asp:ListItem>
        </asp:DropDownList>
        <asp:CompareValidator ID="CompareValidator1" runat="server"
            ErrorMessage="DropDownList 1 can't be equal DropDownList 2"
            ControlToCompare="ddl1" ControlToValidate="ddl2" Operator="NotEqual"></asp:CompareValidator>
        <asp:CompareValidator ID="CompareValidator2" runat="server"
            ErrorMessage="DropDownList 2 can't be equal DropDownList 3"
            ControlToCompare="ddl2" ControlToValidate="ddl3" Operator="NotEqual"></asp:CompareValidator>
         <asp:CompareValidator ID="CompareValidator3" runat="server"
            ErrorMessage="DropDownList 1 can't be equal DropDownList 3"
            ControlToCompare="ddl2" ControlToValidate="ddl3" Operator="NotEqual"></asp:CompareValidator>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: But i have more than two dropdown lists... to compare and listitems are binded from a datatable.

Comment: Please fund the update, and for the Binded ListItems, CompareValidator is validate the value of ListItem so it'll work with you

Comment: what if the dropdowns are created dynamically ., from database, using a repeater. there can be any number of dropdowns.

Comment: In this case DropDownList will be created when you edit/add record and  when you're saving the data do your validation or bind the data which isn't existed in repeater to the DropDownList this will make sure user won't select item exists in repeater.